# Some issue about BufferedReader

Tags: constructor, bufferedreader, filereader

```
 import java.io.*;
```

public class BufferedReaders {

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("e:/test/exercise/BufferedWriter.txt"));
      java.io.BufferedReader bd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("e:/test/exercise/BufferedWriter.txt"));    // The constructor BufferedReader(FileReader) is undefined.***Why?Thanks for your answers!!!***
      String s = null;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s = String.valueOf(Math.random());
        bw.write(s);
        bw.newLine();
      }
      bw.flush();
      while ((s = bd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(s);
      }
      bw.close();
      bd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }                          
}
```

The constructor BufferedReader(FileReader) is undefined. But I just find the code in my book and have a test,I dont know why.Thanks for answering!

Comment: Thank u!Though it is the same.It runs well in yout pc,maybe sth wrong with my pc.I will run it in an other and resovle it.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that code is fine. `BufferedReader` requires a `Reader`, of which `FileReader` is one - it descends from `InputStreamReader`, which descends from `Reader`.

I type that code into Eclipse and it runs fine:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: e:/test/exercise/BufferedWriter.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:99)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

Well, other than the fact it can't open the file (especially since there's no `e:` drive on my Debian box) but that's not a syntax error.

So you have a *different* problem. It's possible, if that's not the whole code, that you have another `BufferedReader` type interfering with the Java one (however unlikely or nefarious) - you could test that by using the fully qualified type after the `new` as well:

```
java.io.BufferedReader bd = new java.io.BufferedReader ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code into Eclipse and write some import statements, and it works.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaders {    
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("e:/test/exercise/BufferedWriter.txt"));
      java.io.BufferedReader bd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("e:/test/exercise/BufferedWriter.txt"));  
      String s = null;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s = String.valueOf(Math.random());
        bw.write(s);
        bw.newLine();
      }
      bw.flush();
      while ((s = bd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(s);
      }
      bw.close();
      bd.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }                          
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.  I also highly recommend taking a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, using that link as a reference can greatly help the visibility and clarity of your answer.